# arquivo de lote para criar banco de dados mysql

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando criar um arquivo de lote .bat para criar o banco de dados e depois recuperar inaformações via arquivo sql, segue o procedimento do arquivo .bat:

```
@echo off
cls
@echo.
@echo Instalando DB
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\
mysql.exe -u root -proot CREATE DATABASE BDNAME
mysql.exe BDNAME < C:\Users\BD.sql
pause
```

O problema é que o código apenas faz o login no MYSQL no shell e não executa os outros procedimentos, como posso arrumar isso ou fazer de outra forma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sintaxe para usar um comando SQL na mesma linha é essa:

```
mysql  --execute="statement"
mysql  -e "statement"
```

No seu caso:

```
mysql.exe -u root -proot -e "CREATE DATABASE BDNAME"
```

(ou você pode simplesmente editar o seu BD.sql e por o `create database` dentro dele, eliminando a 1a chamada ao `mysql.exe`)

Mais detalhes na [documentação oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute) <sup><sup>en</sup></sup>.

Nota: não se esqueça de colocar os parâmetros de login (`-u USER -pSENHA`) no segundo comando, pois é uma sessão totalmente independente (a não ser que você esteja logando no .sql usado, claro)

Comment: obrigado! Vou fazer isso para ficar tudo em um .SQL.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>A [resposta do @Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56172/223) já lida com os teus problemas imediatos, vou deixar uma forma ágil de lidar com a questão:</sup>

## [MySQL em modo batch](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-mode.html)

MySQL pode ser executado em modo batch, o que essencialmente nos permite passar como parâmetro um ficheiro que contém todos os comandos a executar:

```
mysql -h host -u user -p < ficheiro-batch
```

Assim, não é necessário estar constantemente a chamar:

```
 mysql -h host -u user -p -e "comando"
```

Em suma, dentro do `ficheiro-batch` podes ter TODOS os comandos a executar e com uma só linha resolver a questão.

**Nota:**

Nunca guardar a password neste tipo de ficheiros, se não a indicares, ao executares o que sugiro em cima, a mesma vai-te ser solicitada! Assim não corres riscos de segurança.

Comment: obrigado respostas nunca são demais.